# htaccess dynamic rewrite rule, count characters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have thousands of files, and some of the links to those files have an extra `1` appended to them.

Basically, the file-names are all `999999_999999` or `999999_99999` (second half is 5 or 6 digits). I need to redirect all links that have 7 digits for the second half and remove the last digit.

So for example, 062515_1234561 needs to redirect to 062515_123456. Is it possible to count the digits and remove the last one if greater than x?

I suspect I might be thinking about this the wrong way, and I may want to utilize wildcards. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if even repeaters don't work you can write `(\d\d\d\d\d\d)\d`

Comment: Would you be willing to provide an example?

Comment: RewriteRule (\d\d\d\d\d\d_\d\d\d\d\d\d)\d $1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d+_\d{6})\d/?$ /$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: to redirect all links that have 7 digits for the second half